# Organizing interfaces in a C# solution?

Tags: c#, .net, software-design

For a while now, I've been confused on how is the best way to organize a solution. I've later picked up a lot of knowledge on this, I now create multiple projects to separate my projects depending on their use.

Projects

- AppName
- AppName.API
- AppName.Core
- AppName.Common

Now, if the API project contains all the interfaces for my project, does this mean every class must have an interface or is that the best practice? It seems to be near impossible putting all interfaces into `AppName.API` without somehow cross including `AppName` and `AppName.API` or some other project other than `AppName`, is this intended? So that nothing but interfaces are exposed to the API?

Lets say I have a class `Car`, `Car` has to implement `ICar`, what about if this `ICar` needs to access another class that `Car` needs to add but its in `AppName`, `AppName` already references `AppName.API` to include `ICar`, does this mean I need an interface for the class `Car` or more correctly `ICar` requires?

Hopefully, my above statement makes sense.

I'm not sure if that is something that I'm supposed to be doing but I feel its wrong, or I'm just missing a huge piece of the puzzle. Is this the correct way? Am I the only one doing this? Somehow I feel alone.

If anyone could elaborate on this and give me some knowledge I would be much grateful.

Comment: we normally put interfaces in common project which is refered in all other projects

Comment: Welcome. Your question appears to be primarily opinion-based  and if so sadly off-topic for SO. [ask].

Comment: Upvoters and OP should perhaps take a refresher of [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly a question which attracts answers based on users opinions, In my projects, i usually use the namespave as "AppName.ServiceName.Abstracts".

Comment: _"..which attracts answers based on users opinions"_ - just like this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your Interfaces separate is a good practice, however you need to realize an interface is a contract. A contract between the consumer and the implementing party. As such any incoming or outgoing parameter defined on an interface is part of that contract. And so it make sense to bundle these parameter object and related interfaces together in one assembly. If you keep them in separate assemblies you will just end up needing to reference both.

Another point to keep in mind is that interfaces provide a software designer the ability to reverse dependencies(and improve testabillity) as with any tool use it with care and don't assume you have to interface every single class you create.

Lastly in a layered software design it's not uncommon to map entities from one layer to another. This is a result of keeping layer dependencies to a minimum.